# Poor scaling when running code in parallel using MPI and openMP

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, hpc, openmpi

I have the following implementation:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int n_runs = 100; // Number of runs
    int seed = 1; 
    int arraySize = 400;
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   
    // initialise the random number generator using a fixed seed for reproducibility
    srand(seed); 

    MPI_Init(nullptr, nullptr);

    int rank, n_procs;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &n_procs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    // Initialise the probability step and results vectors.
    // We have 21 probabilities between 0 and 1 (inclusive).
    double prob_step = 0.05;
    std::vector<double> avg_steps_over_p(21,0);
    std::vector<double> trans_avg_steps_over_p(21,0);
    std::vector<int> min_steps_over_p(21,0);
    std::vector<int> trans_min_steps_over_p(21,0);
    std::vector<int> max_steps_over_p(21,0);
    std::vector<int> trans_max_steps_over_p(21,0);
    std::vector<double> prob_reached_end(21,0);
    std::vector<double> trans_prob_reached_end(21,0);

    // Loop over probabilities and compute the number of steps before the model burns out,
    // averaged over n_runs.
    for (int i = rank; i < 21; i+=n_procs)
    {
        double prob = i*prob_step;

        int min_steps = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
        int max_steps = 0;

        for (int i_run = 0; i_run < n_runs; ++i_run)
        {
            Results result = forest_fire(arraySize, prob);
            
            avg_steps_over_p[i] += result.stepCount;

            if (result.fireReachedEnd) ++prob_reached_end[i];
            if (result.stepCount < min_steps) min_steps = result.stepCount;
            if (result.stepCount > max_steps) max_steps = result.stepCount;
        }

        avg_steps_over_p[i] /= n_runs;
        min_steps_over_p[i] = min_steps;
        max_steps_over_p[i] = max_steps;
        prob_reached_end[i] = 1.0*prob_reached_end[i] / n_runs;
    }

    // Worker processes communicate their results to the master process.
    if (rank > 0)
    {
        MPI_Send(&avg_steps_over_p[0], 21, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&min_steps_over_p[0], 21, MPI_INT, 0, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&max_steps_over_p[0], 21, MPI_INT, 0, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&prob_reached_end[0], 21, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    } else
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < n_procs; ++i)
        {
            MPI_Status status;
            MPI_Recv(&trans_avg_steps_over_p[0], 21, MPI_DOUBLE, i, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            for (int j = i; j < 21; j += n_procs) {
                 avg_steps_over_p[j] = trans_avg_steps_over_p[j];
            }
            MPI_Recv(&trans_min_steps_over_p[0], 21, MPI_INT, i, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            for (int j = i; j < 21; j += n_procs) {
                 min_steps_over_p[j] = trans_min_steps_over_p[j];
            }

            MPI_Recv(&trans_max_steps_over_p[0], 21, MPI_INT, i, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            for (int j = i; j < 21; j += n_procs) {
                 max_steps_over_p[j] = trans_max_steps_over_p[j];
            }

            MPI_Recv(&trans_prob_reached_end[0], 21, MPI_DOUBLE, i, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            for (int j = i; j < 21; j += n_procs) {
                 prob_reached_end[j] = trans_prob_reached_end[j];
            }
        }

        // Master process outputs the final result.
        std::cout << "Probability, Avg. Steps, Min. Steps, Max Steps" << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 21; ++i)
        {
            double prob = i * prob_step;
            std::cout << prob << "," << avg_steps_over_p[i]
                      << "," << min_steps_over_p[i] << "," 
                      << max_steps_over_p[i] << "," 
                      << prob_reached_end[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried the following parameters: [scaling analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UzU4.png)

I'm new to parallelisation and HPC so forgive me if I'm wrong, but I was expecting a speed-up ratio of greater than 3 when increasing the tasks per node and CPUs per task. I haven't yet tried all the possibilities but I believe the behaviour here is odd, especially when keeping CPUs per task at 1 and increasing tasks per node from 2->3->4. I know it's not as simple a case as greater core usage = greater speed up, but from what I've gathered these should speed-up.

Is there a possible inefficiency in my code that is leading to this, or is this expected behaviour? My full code is here, which includes the openMP parallelisation: https://www.codedump.xyz/cpp/Y5Rr68L8Mncmx1Sd.

Many thanks.

Comment: How do you run MPI? If you do not tweak the execution the number of process run can be the number of core so there is no place for running OpenMP on multiple core in each process. In such a case you can get several threads running on the same core. Besides, even if this does not happen, the location of the thread on the core matters, especially on NUMA architecture. Did you check how thread are mapped or tried to map them ? What is the architecture of the target node(s) (processor specification, number of nodes) ? Finally, note that it takes some time to run MPI, so how long take the program?

Comment: 1. I don't know how many operations are in the `forest_fire` routine but it had better be a couple of tens of thousands otherwise you don't have enough work to overcome the parallelization overhead. 2. Rank 0 handles all processes sequentially. You should use `MPI_Irecv`. And I wonder if a collective operation would not be preferable. 3. You are indexing with `[i]` which is a strided operation. That is space-wasting as I pointed out in another question you posted. Every process should only allocate as much space as is needed on that process.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't know how many operations are in the forest_fire routine but it had better be a couple of tens of thousands otherwise you don't have enough work to overcome the parallelization overhead.
2. Rank 0 handles all processes sequentially. You should use MPI_Irecv. And I wonder if a collective operation would not be preferable.
3. You are indexing with [i] which is a strided operation. That is space-wasting as I pointed out in another question you posted. Every process should only allocate as much space as is needed on that process.

Comment: Apologies, I discovered there was an error with the way my batch script handled openMP paralellisation. Fixing this resulted in expected speed-ups. Regardless, your advice is definitely valid ways I could improve efficiency, so thank you. I am still a beginner so I need to read up to fully understand your answer.